# $\bigcup_{I} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{i_{n}} \in \mathcal{A}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Suppose $A_{n} \in \mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A} - \sigma$-algebra. And $I:=\{ i_{1},i_{2},...,i_{n},...\}$ - some infinite sequence of natural numbers. I need to prove that $\bigcup_{I} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{i_{n}} \in \mathcal{A}$.

It's easy to see that $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{i_{n}} \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $I$. However, the number of infinite sequances is uncountable and I don't know how to solve this problem. Please, give me any hints.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Is each $i_j$ a sequence?

Comment: No, each $I$ is a sequence

Comment: This isn't true. This is the [Suslin $\mathcal A$-operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin_operation), which when applied to the Borel sets (in a complete separable metric space with no isolated points) can produce non-Borel sets. The collection of sets obtainable by applying the $A$-operation to closed sets produces all Borel sets and other sets (collectively called the *analytic sets*). The collection of analytic sets is NOT a $\sigma$-algebra. See also [What are some good intuitions for understanding Souslin's operation $\mathcal{A}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223142/13130)

Comment: Incidentally, the term "$C$ sets" is often used to name the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the analytic sets. It can be formed by a transfinite construction of $\omega_1$ many steps that alternate between applying the Suslin operation and the operation of taking taking complements, and taking the union of all previous collections at the limit ordinal steps. For a little more about $C$ sets, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142762/13130).

Comment: OK. So $I\in ?$